# Enhancement modules for Delphi

Tags: delphi, key-bindings

Embaradaro Help mentions Enhancement modules, but I can find no other material for them. I want to reassign the Debug functions (Step In, Step over etc.) to different keys, and it sounds like it may be possible with enhancement modules.
Can anyone point me to more information?

Comment: Most likely meant: _Tools > Editor Options/Properties > Key Mappings > Enhancement modules_

Answer (score 2):

Embarcadero does not document how to create new "Enhancement modules".  All it does say is the following:

> Enhancement modules are special packages that are installed and registered and **use the keyboard binding features that can be developed using the Open Tools API**. You can create enhancement modules that contain new keystrokes or apply new operations to existing keystrokes. Once installed, the enhancement modules are displayed in the Enhancement modules list box. Clicking the check box next to the enhancement module enables it and unchecking disables it. Key mapping defined in an installed and enabled enhancement module overrides any existing key mapping defined for that key in the key mapping module that is currently in effect.

When it comes to the OpenTools API, you usually have to rely on 3rd party documentation. For instance, have a look at this blog article by Cary Jensen:

[Creating Editor Key Bindings in Delphi](http://caryjensen.blogspot.com/2010/06/creating-editor-key-bindings-in-delphi.html)

> There is a powerful but little known feature of the code editor in Delphi and that permits you to add your own custom keystrokes. This feature is referred to as custom key bindings and it is part of the Delphi open tools API (OTA). The open tools API provides you with a collection of classes and interfaces that you can use to write your own extensions to the IDE.
>
> This article provides you with an overview of this interesting feature, and demonstrates a simple key binding class that you can use as a starting point for creating your own custom key bindings.
> ...

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the Embarcadero Key Bindings but found a very good substution.
I installed keyremapper and, with a simple setup, managed to map F9, F10, F11, and F12 to the four left-most function keys.
Now I can debug without doing the old cross-hand keyboard stuff.

Comment: Welcome to the internet - it works through links. Let me [link to that software](https://atnsoft.com/keyremapper/).